# Share on Facebook FAN page Need PHP Solution

Tags: php, facebook

I am looking for a way to share my Content on My Facebook Fan Page.

This feature is not for public its only for me (admin).

Edit: 
You guys give negative vote at this question.. i just find a way to share on facebook..

http://zeeveloper.com/blog/2010/05/post-on-facebook-fanpage-php-api/

But its unclear for me..

how to create parmanent_session with this script?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can not use those methods as they are now depreciated. rest api is no longer used. You should now try using **Graph api i.e. OAuth 2.0**.

For sharing on fan page you should consult the following link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

You will need `**manage_pages**` and `**publish_stream**` permissions to post on page wall.

Hope that helps.